# iOS-tests with realm.io doesn't work

Tags: ios, testing, realm

I have a simple realm object like this:

```
@interface Person : RLMObject
@property NSString *name;
@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Person)
```

- I already enabled the "Target Membership" for my test project

Now I like to test something with realm.io this way:

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import "Person.h"

@interface PersonTests : XCTestCase
@end

@implementation PersonTests

- (void)setUp {[super setUp];}
- (void)tearDown {[super tearDown];}
- (void)testFooBar
{
    // !!! the test crashes right here!!!!
    Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];


    person.name = @"foobar";

    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];

    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    [realm addObject:person];
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];

    ......
}
```

... but the test crashes in the first line (Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];) with the following error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'objectClass must derive from RLMObject'

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I'm thankful for any hint!!

Comment: Hey Marco, could you share more of your code? I just tried this and it worked fine https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10116/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-03%20at%2010.57.58%20AM.png

Comment: Hi yoshyosh thanks for your fast reply. In my normal project target everything works fine but not in the test target (unit test). So if you try to copy your code in a XCTestCase does it work as well?

Comment: Yes, everything passes for me https://www.dropbox.com/s/a31qjgdqx1jjxot/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-03%20at%202.29.08%20PM.png?dl=0
Can you share your code?

Comment: Hey yoshyosh, thanks for showing me your solution! The problem was that I added realm.io via pod-file and it doesn't worked even if I linked the pod file with the testing project. Anyway if I add the library directly everything works fine. Thank you!

Comment: It would be great if you could add the solution to this question. The dropbox link above 404's. Thanks

Comment: I waste 3 hours for this bug, thank you for saving me.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same error, and after 4 hours of delete, clone, clean, re-install pods, repeat... what works for me is:

## Podfile

```
link_with 'MyProject', 'MyProjectTests'

#common pods such as CocoaLumberjack

pod 'Realm', '0.89.0'

target 'MyProjectTests', exclusive: true do
  pod 'Realm/Headers'
end
```

## TestFile

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
#import "RealmObjectSubclass.h"

- (void)setUp {
  [super setUp];
  NSString *resourcePath = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self.class]].resourcePath;
  NSString *testRealPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.test", resourcePath];
  [RLMRealm setDefaultRealmPath:testRealPath];
}
```